# How to check if EC2 is associated with proper policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

In my company I have no access to AWS console but our company's AWS administrator creates an EC2 instance and lets me access to it through ssh.

When I ask for a creation of EC2 instance, I give the policies I need for the EC2 instance.

However, the administrator often forgets to associate some policies to the EC2 instance.

Therefore, I want to automate the process of checking my EC2 instance if it has enought authority to do some behaviors for example as below.

```
Action: cloudwatch:GetMetricData - Resource: *
Action: rds:DescribeExportTasks - Resource: *
Action: rds:StartExportTask - Resource: *
Action: rds:DescribeDBSnapshots - Resource: arn:aws:rds::region:account:snapshot:*
```

I did some research and reached to aws-cli and found some commands for checking so but wondering if there are any ways to do so without asking for more authority just for checking the instance.

Comment: not the ec2, your user is associated with the policies, By ec2 policy can you elaborate more.

Comment: I think he means EC2 role

Comment: Yes I meant EC2 role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the policies attached to your EC2 instance with few steps.
**1: Get the name of your EC2 role.**
`aws ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations --filters Name=instance-id,Values=i-123456789`
You will get role name with the above command.

**2: List role policies**
`aws iam list-role-policies --role-name my-instance-role-name`
With the above command you will get all the policies attached to it.

**3: Describe policies.**
`aws iam get-role-policy --role-name my-instance-role-name --policy-name attachedpolicyname`
With the above command, you will get the polciy in `json`.

***UPDATE: With the `get-role-policy` you get only the inline policies.***

For other policies, you need one more step.

**4: List non-inline policies attahced to the role.**
`aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name my-instance-role-name`

Comment: By doing the second step('List role policies'), I only see the in-line policies. Is there a way to see also the managed policies?

Comment: I figured out. Thank you so much.
aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name role

Comment: Yes, my bad I forgot managed policies.